# Evolution on Debian 7 won't restore Evolution back up file from Fedora 18

Tags: linux, backup, debian, fedora, evolution

I made a back up of my Evolution mail client when my laptop was using Fedora 18. Today, I have finished installing Debian 7 on to the same laptop, and now I am trying to restore the back up file to the new installation.

However, every time I go to restore the back up file, Evolution finds the file and starts to restore the backup. Evolution then restarts, but nothing has been restored? I've tried several times now and it still does the same, nothing gets restored. Not even the emails. It also doesn't give an error or any indication there was a problem, it also doesn't give an indication that it's actually been successful.

I had about 20,000 emails on my Evolution client before I put Debian on to the system. The back up .tar.gz file is 382MB in size, and when I uncompress it it goes up to 998MB in size, so I'm confident all of my emails are actually contained in the back up file. I'm just at a loss to explain as to why Evolution on Debian isn't restoring the backup file created by Evolution in Fedora.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much trial and error, I discovered what the problem is.

Evolution on Fedora 18 (which is what I was running) uses Evolution 3.6. Evolution on Debian 7 uses Evolution 3.4. So from my reckoning, you can't restore your data from a newer version of Evolution to an older version.

The work around that I managed to do was unzip the .tar.gz backup file, which should leave you with 2 folders: `.config` and `.local`. I copied the contents of both folders to their respective folders on my laptop, and I retrieved all of my emails. However, the settings for the email accounts weren't transferred.